# Library to Tidy Up Python Code using pep8 conventions

Tags: python, code-formatting, pep8

Is there any library that takes in your python file as input and does tidy-up *(modifies it based on the `PEP 8` conventions)*.
To understand what I am talking about, a `JavaScript` analogy is as follows:

1. Go to this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve_Wellens/pBtQf/)
2. Press the button **TidyUp**

Any online editor or library or script would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look to [PythonTidy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy/) which is officially working till python2.5 (and seems to be supported in python2.6) :

> Cleans up, regularizes, and reformats the text of Python scripts.
>
> This script reads Python code from standard input and writes a revised
>   version to standard output.

Comment: this is not anyways the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

[pep8.py](https://github.com/cburroughs/pep8.py) gives you warnings for violations. Doesn't actually correct though.

Comment: Yup but this is closest thing I could find which might be useful.